# Python numpy array integer indexed flat slice assignment

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, slice

Was experimenting with numpy and found this strange behavior.
This code works ok:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])    
>>> a[:, 1].flat[:] = np.array([-1, -1])
>>> a 
array([[ 1, -1,  3],
       [ 4, -1,  6]])
```

But why this code doesn't change to -1 elements of 0 and 2 column?

```
>>> a[:, [0, 2]].flat[:] = np.array([-1, -1])
>>> a 
array([[ 1, -1,  3],
       [ 4, -1,  6]])
```

And how to write the code so that would change to -1 elements of 0 and 2 columns like this?

UPD: use of `flat` or smt similar is necessarily in my example

UPD2: I made example in question basing on this code:

```
img = imread(img_name)
xor_mask = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.bool)
# msg_bits looks like array([ True, False, False, ..., False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
xor_mask[:, :, channel].flat[:len(msg_bits)] = np.ones_like(msg_bits, dtype=np.bool)
```

And after assignment to xor mask with channel == 0 or 1 or 2 code works ok, but if channel == [1,2] or smt like this, assignment does not happen

Comment: It's not clear *why* you need to use `flat`. As already answered below, `flat` may create a copy therefore your updates may not change the original array. Explain why you need `flat` at all and maybe you can get a solution.

Comment: @lbolla updated question

Comment: @ЮраМахоткин Seems you are stuck in an [`XY problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Divakar yeah, you right. I will post question again but with correct problem formulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others has pointed out `.flat` may create a copy of the original vector, so any updates to it would be lost. But `flat`tening a 1D slice is fine, so you can use a `for` loop to update multiple indexes.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
a[:, 1].flat = np.array([-1, -1])
print a

# Use for loop to avoid copies
for idx in [0, 2]:
     a[:, idx].flat = np.array([-1, -1])
print a
```

Note that you don't need to use `flat[:]`: just `flat` is enough (and probably more efficient).

Comment: What's not to like about it?

Comment: Nothing, but i'm learning numpy and expected some numpy construction for this situation

Comment: Well, you seem to be fixed on using `flat`, but `flat` must create a copy in your situation, so it can't be used. I think you simply have to "tune" your expectations...

Comment: But wait. For-loop doesn't fit to my needs: `xor_mask[:, :, channel].flat[:len(msg_bits)] = np.ones_like(msg_bits, dtype=np.bool)` and `for ch in channel: xor_mask[:, :, ch].flat[:len(msg_bits)] = np.ones_like(msg_bits, dtype=np.bool)` logically does different process

Comment: You've got to break `msg_bits` accordingly. I don't know why you are fixated with using `flat`, so I can't give you a meaningful recommendation.

Comment: i get answer in another question topic, because as someone here pointed to me, i'm stuck in XY problem

Answer (score 2):

In first example by flattening the slice you don't change the shape and actually the <strike>python</strike> Numpy  doesn't create a new object. so assigning to flattened slice is like assigning to actual slice. But by flattening a 2d array you're changing the shape and hence numpy makes a copy of it.

also you don't need to flatten your slice to add to it:

```
In [5]: a[:, [0, 2]] += 100

In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[101,   2, 103],
       [104,   5, 106]])
```

Comment: This example from other problem, there is necessarily to use `flat`. Can you explain how to do with `flat`?

Comment: @ЮраМахоткин Pleas add the use case to question, it's hard to answer like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the `flat[:]` `from a[:, [0, 2]].flat[:] += 100`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a[:, 1].flat[:] += 100
>>> a
array([[  1, 102,   3],
       [  4, 105,   6]])
>>> a[:, [0, 2]] += 100
>>> a
array([[101, 102, 103],
       [104, 105, 106]])
```

But you say it is necessary... Can't you just [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) whatever you are trying to add to the initial array instead of using `flat`?

The second index call makes a copy of the array while the first returns a reference to it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> b = a[:,1].flat
>>> b[0] += 100
>>> a
array([[  1, 102,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6]])
>>> b =a[:,[0,2]].flat
>>> b[0]
1
>>> b[0] += 100
>>> a
array([[  1, 102,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6]])
>>> b[:]
array([101,   3,   4,   6])
```

It appears that when the elements you wish to iterate upon in a `flat` maner are not adjacent numpy makes an iterator over a copy of the array.